# Slack bot not allowing users to submit, "We had some trouble connecting. Try again?"

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api, bolt

I'm trying to get a slack bot to create a modal which is then responded to by app.views. I use socket mode. Whenever you press submit, it says "We had some trouble connecting. Try again?" and does not allow the user to submit. Does anyone have any fixes for this? I have attempted to also use ProcessBeforeResponse to rectify the issue, but it seems that it does not change the result.

```
app.command("/bugreport", async ({ command, ack, say}) => {   try {
        app.client.dialog.open(
          {
          "trigger_id": command.trigger_id,
          "dialog": {
            "callback_id": "bug-report",
            "title": "Make an issue",
            "submit_label": "Request",
            "notify_on_cancel": true,
            "state": "idk",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "label": "Your Name",
                    "name": "username"
                },
                {
                  "type": "select",
                  "label": "Issue Severity",
                  "name": "severity",
                  "options": [
                    {
                      "label": "Minor",
                      "value": "minor"
                    },
                    {
                      "label": "Moderate",
                      "value": "moderate"
                    },
                    {
                      "label": "Urgent",
                      "value": "urgent"
                    },                
                    {
                      "label": "Critical",
                      "value": "critical"
                    }
                  ]
    
                },
                {
                  "label": "Description",
                  "name": "description",
                  "type": "textarea",
                  "hint": "Describe the bug in this section. Be thorough and explain the exact cause of the bug"
                },
                {
                  "label": "Bug timeline",
                  "name": "timeline",
                  "type": "text",
                  "placeholder": "When did this issue first appear"
                },
                {
                  "label": "Expected Behaviour",
                  "name": "excpectedBehaviour",
                  "type": "textarea",
                  "hint": "Detail what you expected the code to do. Just what it was meant to do."
                },
                {
                  "label": "Actual Behaviour",
                  "name": "actualBehaviour",
                  "type": "textarea",
                  "hint": "What actually happened, what was different."
                },   
                {
                  "label": "Steps to reproduce",
                  "name": "steps",  
                  "type": "textarea",
                  "placeholder": "1. [First Step]...\n 2. [Second Step]... \n 3. [And so on]... \n"
                },     
                {
                  "label": "Additional Information",
                  "name": "additionalInformation",
                  "type": "textarea",
                  "hint": "Anything extra to include."
                }
                
            ]
    
          }
          
          }
          
          )
          await ack();
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("err")
        console.error(error);   } });
```

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to my  [answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75901659/8479303),

I assume this would have come down to missing the `Request URL` configuration in the `Interactivity & Shortcuts` feature of the Slack App config.

The Request URL for interactivity gets saved separately from the Request URL slash commands. So if you had it configured for one but not the other, you could end up with the modal appearing when you enter your slash command, but none of the interaction handlers working.